# Can we save string as a value in OpenTSDB?

Tags: time-series, opentsdb

I am trying to save string data in opentsdb, but its is giving my error, can someone help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

> Can we save string as a value in OpenTSDB?

**No**.

It's a time-series database i.e. made for storing int/float values at a particular instance of time.

---

From OpenTSDB [docs](http://opentsdb.net/overview.html):

> In OpenTSDB, a time series data point consists of:
>
> - A metric name.
> - A UNIX timestamp (seconds or millisecinds since Epoch).
> - **A value (64 bit integer or single-precision floating point value).**
> - A set of tags (key-value pairs) that describe the time series the point belongs to.

Answer (score -1):

Use "put name timestamp value [tags]" commands are the network protocol for saving data into the OpenTSDB over TCP/IP.